# Change color map for ezsurf in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using a simple code to draw the 'Rosenbrock function'.

```
clear all;
clc;

syms x1 x2 st;

% Rosenbrock function
f = 100*(x2-x1^2)^2+(1-x1)^2;

% plot
figure(1);
ezsurfc(f,[-2,2,0,2]);
drawnow;
```

[image]

How can I change the colormap of the figure so that the ups/downs of the figure is more clear, for example around point (x1, x2) = (-1.2, 1). Following [this link](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html), 'colormap Lines' does the work somehow. But is there a better way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to that same link, you don't *have* to use predefined color maps; you can create one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the contour3 command instead of ezsurfc.